# Make SSH tunnel to query a remote redshift database in R

Tags: python, r

I am using the below Python code to get data from a remote Redshift database. I am using this function with the reticulate package in R. I want to convert the Python code to R so that I do not face the hassle of setting up an Anaconda environment in the cloud when I push my code (shiny app) to shipapps.io. I read about the [SSH package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssh/vignettes/intro.html) and its capabilities but I could not successfully convert my code using it.

```
 def get_redshift_data(query):
  import pandas as pd
  from sqlalchemy import create_engine
  from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData
  import pymysql
  import paramiko
  from paramiko import SSHClient
  from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
  from sqlalchemy.engine import url as u

  mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('nfw-linux-key.pem')
  sql_username = 'my_sql_username'
  sql_hostname = 'sql_username@xxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com'
  sql_password = 'my_sql_password'
  sql_main_database = 'my_db'
  sql_port = 5439
  ssh_host = '127.0.0.1'
  ssh_user = 'ubuntu'
  ssh_port = 56714
  sql_ip = '1.1.1.1.1'
  with SSHTunnelForwarder(
          (ssh_host, ssh_port),
          ssh_username=ssh_user,
          ssh_pkey=mypkey,
          remote_bind_address=(sql_hostname, sql_port)) as tunnel:
      conn_url = u.URL(drivername='postgresql+psycopg2', username=sql_username, 
                   password=sql_password, host='127.0.0.1', 
                   port=tunnel.local_bind_port, database=sql_main_database)
      conn = create_engine(conn_url)
      result = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
  return result
```

Then I am sourcing the Python function above to get data from the database.

```
library(reticulate)
source_python("get_redshift_data.py")
df = get_redshift_data("select top 100 * from my_db.my_table")
```

But I want to avoid the Python part and use R only.